# difference between Firefox and Chrome padding

Tags: css

there is a difference in how firefox and chrome render the padding in css.
what appears correct in chrome is extra padded in firefox. is there a way to solve?

```
.button {
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    font-size: 64px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin: 7px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure this isn't a `line-height` issue?

Comment: If you have a demonstration page, that would help.

Comment: in this demo I don't see any difference http://jsfiddle.net/W22DC/

Comment: As far as I see it, it's extra padded in Chrome.

Comment: What tag are you applying `.button` to?

Comment: You should look into using a CSS reset. This will solve these sorts of issues 90% of the time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your .button is a `button` this might be a mozilla inner focus thing... try this?

```
.button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; margin:0; }
```

Comment: Thankyou... 2 hours wasted but it could have been much more without this answer... ;)

Comment: This fixes the problem.. what are Mozilla thinking? :|

Comment: sorry for taking this long to accept the answer. lost track. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

Firefox and Chrome render `padding` exactly the same way. Your problem is elsewhere.

Are you using a reset CSS? If not, the default `line-height` declaration might be interfering with the rendering of your button.

For one, your `height` is way smaller than your `font-size`. Since you don't have `overflow` specified, your `height` will always be extended to at least `font-size` (or whatever your `line-height` specifies).

If your `.button` class is actually a `<button>` element, also apply [superUntitled fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370609/difference-between-firefox-and-chrome-padding/5370626#5370626).

Comment: In Firefox, the width/height of a div is given width/height+padding. In other browsers, the padding does not add that to the size of the div.

Comment: What's the role of reset.css in rendering padding? I'm using a child theme for wordpress and I'm seeing different extent of padding for firefox and chrome.

Comment: @poepje: That's untrue. Firefox uses the W3C box model.

@Chirag: Different browsers have different values for the default style of elements. A `reset.css` normalizes those values so that your base styles are the same across all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The focus-inner fix works but I also add negative top and bottom margins to get it to the right height. e.g.:

```
*::-moz-focus-inner {
padding: 0;
border: 0;
margin-top:-1px;
margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

I used to love Firefox, but it has become a bloated mess and fell off my Christmas list years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually correct - there is a bug in Firefox where the button element's line height cannot be changed with the CSS line-height property.

See this link for details: http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/

The solution is to use padding instead of line-height.

Answer (score 0):

u can set a different padding for firefox

```
.button {
   padding:0;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .button {
       padding:10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way that worked for me was to set the height of the object so that firefox, chrome and opera render it the same way, and remove all padding.

```
.footertext6{
    float: left;
    padding-top:10px;
    width: 160px;
    height:102px; */setting height here*/
    background-color:#ffffff;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;    
}
```