# change css for firefox

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I have read extensively on this site and others about how to change my css for different browsers, but none of the methods I have found are working.

I have an unordered list whose list items appear with different amounts of padding on different browsers. The value is set to 8 px and works perfectly on chrome and safari. I have tried

```
ul.titles li {

padding: 8px;
-moz-padding: 7px;
font-family:"Subway", "Courier New", "serif";
font-size:11;
color: #000000;
}
```

I also tried

```
ul.titles li {

padding: 8px;
padding: -moz-7px;
font-family:"Subway", "Courier New", "serif";
font-size:11;
color: #000000;
}
```

Both of these had no effect. When I tried defining one for -webkit- and one for -moz- it messed up both mozilla and chrome.

Comment: You should consider starting your CSS with a CSS reset or normalizer.

Comment: This thread may be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370609/difference-between-firefox-and-chrome-padding

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser specific CSS padding for firefox field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569399/browser-specific-css-padding-for-firefox-field)

Comment: I see that the problem may be line-height not padding - still though, I need some way to specify the line-height for mozilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your styles inside of a Mozilla extension:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* Styles go here */
}
```

So in your case, you can add the following lines of code to your CSS stylesheet:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
     ul.titles li {
        padding: 8px;
        font-family:"Subway", "Courier New", "serif";
        font-size:11;
        color: #000000;
     }
}
```

Another option you might want to try is [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), which makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing. I highly recommend it.

Comment: This is another one which I've tried with no result- here's what I put for url-prefix (I'm working with apache right now):

@-moz-document localhost {

 ul.titles li {
     padding: 6px;
     font-family:"Subway", "Courier New", "serif";
     font-size:11;
     color: #000000;
 }
}

Comment: @JonathanBasile, it doesn't work like that you. You just copy the CSS code into your stylesheet, put your styles between the brackets that come after `url-prefix()` and it will be formatted in FireFox.

Comment: @JonathanBasile, it's okay. It happens to the best of us. Plus, we all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    ul.titles li {
        padding: 7px;
    }
}
```

for sure otherwrite your css maybe add a `class` to your `li`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of addressing every browser one by one, I suggest using [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to make common elements begin with common styles. A must have for every single website I develop.